# How can I create a virtual switch which allows the virtual client to communicate with the host but not with the internet

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise and the Hyper-V Manager.

- I want that my virtual machine is able to see the host but not the
  cooperate network and internet.
- I want to be able to connect from
  the host via remote desktop to the virtual machine.

How can I create a [virtual switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines) which allows the virtual client to communicate with the host but not with the internet:

[image]

- If I set the connection type to internal I'm able to do a remote desktop connection to my virtual machine. But the virtual machine sees the internet.
- If I set the connection type to private I'm not able to do a remote desktop connection to my virtual machine.
- If I set the connection type to external and I would have 3 Ethernet adapter in my host PC then it could work. Ethernet 1 connected to internet, Ethernet 2 (fix IP e.g.: 192.168.1.1), Ethernet 3 (chosen as external network adapter for the virtual machine fix IP e.g.: 192.168.1.2). If there is a physical connection (Ethernet cable) between adapters 2 and 3 I'm able to do a remote desktop connection from my host to the virtual machine and the virtual machine isn't connected to the internet. So exactly what I want. The problem is that I don't have 3 Ethernet adapter in my host. I'm pretty sure there is an easier way.

Comment: “But the virtual machine sees the internet.” – How did you check that? Did you perhaps accidentally bridge the virtual network connection with your physical network?

Comment: *But the virtual machine sees the internet.* Check your host OS do NOT route VM's traffic to Inet.

Comment: @Akina how can I check that?

Comment: @DanielB I check that by opening a browser in the virtual machine.

Comment: @DanielB I was using the `Default Switch` which use as connection type internal but it does NAT. If I create a new virtual switch with connection type internal then the vm doesn't see the internet.

Comment: I don’t use Hyper-V but I very much doubt it does NAT by default. You probably activated Internet Connection Sharing at some point in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the `Default Switch` which uses as connection type internal. But the `Default Switch` does NAT. The following steps solved my problem:

1. Create a new virtual switch with connection type internal.
2. Assign a fix IP to the vEthernet adapter on the host (e.g.:192.168.1.1)
3. Assign a fix IP to the Ethernet adapter in the virtual machine (e.g.:192.168.1.2)

Like that I'm able to do a remote desktop connection from my host to my virtual machine and my virtual machine isn't connected to the internet.